# .htaccess file paths for css

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, web

I am new to website building. I have a index.html hosted on a public domain and cant figure out how to link my style sheets properly so they are implimented on a webpage.

I have this for the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Oops, nothing's here!</h1>
      <p>It looks like I'm still developing my website. Check back later and there might be something here.</p>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

However the style sheet does not work on the website when its live.
the file path is as follows:

```
/~ 
     index.html
     .htaaccess
     /css<br>
          master.css
```

How do I fix this?

If it helps, this is what is written in my .htaaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```

Comment: Perhaps try `href="css/master.css"` ?

Comment: @NickParsons Sadly that hasn't worked :/

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your cache? Maybe try visiting your site in [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) or on a browser you haven't used yet (or clear cache in your developer tools in your browser)

Comment: I have tried that also to no luck

Comment: Your file .htaaccess should be .htaccess btw.